# Using SprayJson when json fields are optional

Tags: scala, spray-json

I am writing a Scala restful API and using SprayJson to parse the JSON that is being passed in during a Post call.  For example, we have a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"}
```

Fields a, b, c and h are required but the others are not.  I have a custom JSON formatter for my case class.  For various reasons, the way I need to structure the case class requires me to do the custom JSON formatter.

Here is a code snippet of my read function in the formatter:

```
def read(value: JsValue) = {
    value.asJsObject.getFields("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h")
    case Seq(JsString(a),JsString(b),JsString(c),JsString(d),JsString(e),JsString(f),JsString(g),JsString(h))
    new Object(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
    case _ => throw new DeserializationException("Object expected")
}
```

How can I implement the above without having numerous case strings matching every possible permutation of fields that may come in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not familiar with spray-json, but if not existed fields are treated as some kind of `JNull` then you can try this:

```
implicit def JsValueToString(v: JsValue): String = v match {
  case JsString(s) => s
  case _ => null
}
...
case Seq(JsString(a),JsString(b),JsString(c), dOpt, eOpt,fOpt,gOpt,JsString(h)) =>
    new Object(a,b,c,dOpt,eOpt,fOpt,gOpt,h)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to write your own formatter, use Option for optional fields

```
 case class Data(a: String, b: String, c: String, d: Option[String], e:
 Option[String], f: Option[String], g: Option[String], h: String)

   jsonFormat8(Data)
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, I've tried that approach early on and it doesn't work for my particular case.  I'm using an annotation approach on my case classes to convert them into an Avro Schema, so my case class is defined as such:     case class (Data var a: String, var b: String, etc....)  In setting the fields up as var, I no longer get the data passed into the case class from the JSON parsing.  Do you, or anyone else know of, an approach where I can use a single case class, with a custom JSON formatter that will accept JSON (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) and JSON(a,b,c,f,h) in one construct.  -- Thanks,

Comment: Does not work for me. If I define jsonFormat8, but get only 7 fields (one of them was None) then I have an exception